# Autohide columns if cell value is true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With Google Sheets, there's a checkbox feature that is written as TRUE if checked and FALSE if unchecked. I'm trying to find a way to hide rows whose checkbox is checked (or == TRUE) in column B. However, the script isn't working and I can't figure out why.

```
function onOpen() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Scrum');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('B:B')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 'TRUE') 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a that the standard checkbox returns a boolean.

This can be either `true` or `false` but NOT `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which are undefined in Javascript.

So these will properly test the cell value:

```
if (r[0] == true)           // test for boolean true
      s.hideRows(i + 1);

or

if (r[0]) 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);    // test for boolean true
```

but not

```
if (r[0] == 'TRUE')          // 'TRUE' is a string value
      s.hideRows(i + 1);

 or

if (r[0] == TRUE)            // TRUE is an undefined constant.
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
```

NOW the super confusing thing is that in formulas true/false are case insensitive. (TRUE/FALSE and true/false are the same). So be careful!!

Also note that range `s.getRange('B:B')` is the entire 1000 rows so that can slow. Best to restrict the range line `B1:B20` for example. Nt sure is this is an issue for you...

EDIT: Below is a working script:

```
function hide() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());

  var values = sheet.getRange('E1:E7').getValues();

  values.forEach( function (r, i) {
    Logger.log(r);
    if (r[0]) 
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }); 
}
```

Before script:

[image]

After script:

[image]

Comment: I tried both and neither worked. All rows remain visible where B is true.

Comment: I will add the script I used to test and was working fine. If you can't get this working, then let me know.

Comment: when you go to a checkbox what do you see as the value where its says Fx. See my before sheet showing `FALSE` for example. What is yours saying?

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you!  One thing I did notice is that it also hides the top, frozen row even though there is no checkbox there.